# Dataframe: compare column value and one row below

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, np

I have a dataframe with directions:

```
        Direction: 
2/01/19 None
1/31/19 Upward
1/30/19 None
1/29/19 None
1/28/19 Downward
1/27/19 None
1/26/19 None
1/25/19 Upward
```

I want to create a "Momentum" column based on the following conditions (starting at 1/25/19):  
 1. If the Direction for the corresponding date is 'Upward', then set the value to 'Upward' 
2. If the row one below in Momentum is "Upward" set it to 'Upward' 
3. If the Direction for the corresponding date is 'Downward', then set it to 'None'
4. Otherwise, set it to 'None'

Said differently, once you reach the 'Upward' status, it should stay that way until you hit 'Downward'

The result should look like:

```
        Direction:  Momentum:
2/01/19 None        Upward
1/31/19 Upward      Upward
1/30/19 None        None
1/29/19 None        None
1/28/19 Downward    None
1/27/19 None        Upward
1/26/19 None        Upward
1/25/19 Upward      Upward
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without using loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED answer by new data first back fill `None` values and then replace `Downward` to `None`s:

```
#first replace strings Nones to None type
df['Direction:'] = df['Direction:'].mask(df['Direction:'] == 'None', None)
```

```
df['Momentum:'] = df['Direction:'].bfill().mask(lambda x: x == 'Downward', None)
```

Or:

```
s = df['Direction:'].bfill()
df['Momentum:'] = s.mask(s == 'Downward', None)
```

---

```
print (df)
        Direction:  Momentum:
2/01/19       None     Upward
1/31/19     Upward     Upward
1/30/19       None       None
1/29/19       None       None
1/28/19   Downward       None
1/27/19       None     Upward
1/26/19       None     Upward
1/25/19     Upward     Upward
```

Old answer:

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with chained boolean mask compared shifted values and also original by `|` for bitwise OR:

```
mask = df['Direction:'].eq('Upward') | df['Direction:'].shift(-1).eq('Upward')
df['Momentum:'] = np.where(mask, 'Upward', None)
print (df)
        Direction: Momentum:
1/31/19       None    Upward
1/30/19     Upward    Upward
1/29/19       None      None
1/28/19       None      None
1/27/19   Downward      None
1/26/19       None    Upward
1/25/19     Upward    Upward
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. FYI: I edited my original post per @Alexander 's suggestion below.

Comment: @Drive2blue - yop, I think this new data edited few minutes ago.

Comment: hmmm...I'm not getting the same result when I tried your suggestions using the back fill. My momentum column comes out to be an exact copy of Direction except Downward is replaced with None

Comment: @Drive2blue - Maybe `None`s are strings, how working `df['Direction:'] = df['Direction:'].mask(df['Direction:'] == 'None', None)` before my solution ?

Comment: Ah! That's it. It's working now :) Much appreciated!

Comment: @Drive2blue - Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way.  I'll try to improve upon it after some coffee...

```
df['Momentum:'] = None  # Base case.
df.loc[df['Direction:'].eq('Upward'), 'Momentum:'] = 'Upward'
df.loc[df['Direction:'].eq('Downward'), 'Momentum:'] = 1  # Temporary value.
df.loc[:, 'Momentum:'] = df['Momentum:'].bfill()
df.loc[df['Momentum:'].eq(1), 'Momentum:'] = None  # Set temporary value back to None.
>>> df
        Direction: Momentum:
2/01/19       None    Upward
1/31/19     Upward    Upward
1/30/19       None      None
1/29/19       None      None
1/28/19   Downward      None
1/27/19       None    Upward
1/26/19       None    Upward
1/25/19     Upward    Upward
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But this doesn't work if there are two or more consecutive 'None'. Once you reach 'Upward' status, it should stay that way until you hit 'Downward'

Comment: Can you please modify your example to include such a case?

Comment: Amazing!! Many thanks @Alexander for the edited response!